# java conversion of arabic numbers to roman numerals

Tags: java

Im writing this program for a java class im having. The point of this program is to convert an Arabic number input, into a Roman numeral.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanDigit{
public static void main(String arg []){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number to be converted to roman numerals: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    String romanDigit = "";
    if (number < 0 || number > 3999) {
        System.out.println( "This number cannot be converted");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The number you input, converted into roman numerals is: " + romanDigit);
        System.out.println(convert(number));
    }
}



    public static String romanDigit(int n, String one, String five, String ten){

    if(n >= 1)
    {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            return one;
        }
        else if (n == 2)
        {
            return one + one;
        }
        else if (n == 3)
        {
            return one + one + one;
        }
        else if (n==4)
        {
            return one + five;
        }
        else if (n == 5)
        {
            return five;
        }
        else if (n == 6)
        {
            return five + one;
        }
        else if (n == 7)
        {
            return five + one + one;
        }
        else if (n == 8)
        {
            return five + one + one + one;
        }
        else if (n == 9)
        {
            return one + ten;
        }

    }
    return "";
}

public static String convert(int number){

    String romanOnes = romanDigit( number%10, "I", "V", "X");
    number /=10;
    String romanTens = romanDigit( number%10, "X", "L", "C");
    number /=10;
    String romanHundreds = romanDigit(number%10, "C", "D", "M");
    number /=10;
    String romanThousands = romanDigit(number%10, "M", "", "");

    String result = romanThousands + romanHundreds + romanTens + romanOnes;
    return result;

}
}
```

I edited the code now for the given suggestions. I noticed I was missing the number /= 10; statement in the end. For some reason i deleted it before and forgot to put it back. Seems to be working fine now. The reason it was not working besides the number/=10 statement, was that I had the If statement in the wrong place.

Comment: What test have you used? I have just tested with input 5, and I got this output `The number you input, converted into roman numerals is: 
DLV` -- which is, obviously, is not the correct answer.

Comment: You're always passing number%10, i.e. the last digit of the arabic number, to all the methods.

Comment: `String romanOnes = romanDigit( number%10, "I", "V", "X");

        String romanTens = romanDigit( number%10, "X", "L", "C");

        String romanHundreds = romanDigit(number%10, "C", "D", "M");

        String romanThousands = romanDigit(number%10, "M", "", "");`

this can't be the code you're using, if you think it's working fine up until 3999...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `convert` method to be something like this.

```
public static String convert(int number) {
    if (number < 0 || number > 3999) {
        return "This number cannot be converted";
    }

    String romanOnes = romanDigit(number % 10, "I", "V", "X");
    number /= 10;

    String romanTens = romanDigit(number % 10, "X", "L", "C");
    number /= 10;

    String romanHundreds = romanDigit(number % 10, "C", "D", "M");
    number /= 10;

    String romanThousands = romanDigit(number % 10, "M", "", "");
    number /= 10;

    String result = romanThousands + romanHundreds + romanTens + romanOnes;
    return result;
}
```

Also, you should remove checking is a number greater than zero and less than 4000 from `romanDigit` method.

As @eis has noticed, the check does a number is valid for conversion you should check outside of `convert` method. In this case, in the main method.

Comment: `Please enter a number to be converted to roman numerals: 
20
The number you input, converted into roman numerals is: 
XX`

Comment: `Please enter a number to be converted to roman numerals: 
90
The number you input, converted into roman numerals is: 
XC`

Comment: it is working for 10, 20 etc... but if i change the statement that checks if the number < 0 || number > 3999 to the main method, the code will convert the number and at the same time display the message that it cannot be converted. If I keep this statement in the convert method this does not happen.

Comment: @Miguel  - for that purpose you shoud use if statemen. 
```if (number < 0 || number > 3999) {
  System.out.println("This number cannot be converted");
 } else {
  String romanDigit = "";
  System.out.println("The number you input, converted into roman numerals is: " + romanDigit);
  System.out.println(convert(number));
 }```